# check_box_tag boxes don't get sent in params on first attempt after page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a rails app with a page containing a form_for. Within the form there is a table with a series of rows that looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= u.email %></td>
  <td class="action"><%= check_box_tag "contactlist[]", u.id, false, {onclick:"check()", class:"emailrow"} %></td>
</tr>
```

There is a submit_tag button for the form which goes to a controller method. If I insert a "puts params" into the first line of the controller method, I see the below:

```
parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PgjBBtPoMk2tBbJ5soWpP7kHyNFqA+4p//B2IE0ta/OFnpY0u8To4wFg0PUiuGq81Yu+f2+Lxm9KutrRXOp7wg==", "delete"=>"Delete Selected", "contactlist"=>["77"], "method"=>"post"}
```

However, the first time I try to submit the form after a page refresh, there is no "contactlist" in the parameters, despite the checkboxes being checked. If I re-check the checkboxes after submitting it once unsuccessfully, the "contactlist" portion then appears.

Using rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.2.3p173

EDIT: Full form info:

```
 <%= form_for :topics, :url => {:action => "topics_act", :method => "post"} do %>
<%= text_field :query, nil, :placeholder => "Enter term(s)", :id => "newtopic", :size => 20 %>
 <%= submit_tag "Add Topic", 'data-disable-with' => "Processing", name:"add_topic" %>
<%= submit_tag "Save Selected", 'data-disable-with' => "Processing", name:'save' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Delete Selected", 'data-disable-with' => "Processing", name:'delete' %>
<td class="action"><%= check_box_tag "itemlist[]", item.id %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: try this checkbox: `<%= check_box_tag "contactlist[]", 'u.id', false %>`. No class and without onclick method bs. Every time I run into some bugs, I "undress" my code.

Comment: forgot to ask. Please post your form code, it will be a hell faster to pin point the problem. thanks.

Comment: @RareFever tried that but no luck, edited above with all form fields

Comment: Every form_for must have at the end this: `<% end %>`.  Well, unfortunatly your form_for is incorrect. The first line should end like: `do |f| %>`. And each of the attributes should start like this: `<%= f.text_field ...%>`. I recomend you very strongly to read this topic called [**Binding a Form to an Object**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Comment: Thanks, neither of those are the issue though. Again, it works the second time, the issue is the checkbox parameters are not being sent through the first time the form is submitted

Comment: It seems to have to do with the fact that the check_box_tags are below the submit_tags in the form, moving the submit_tags below the check_box_tag seems to fix it.

Comment: as I said, your form_for was incorrect. I am happy that you solved the problem ! ;) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles across this, the issue was due to turbolinks in Rails 4. Putting data-no-turbolink="true" inside the body tag fixed the issue